# Create Video Player (Quicktime browser plugin) React Elements, output missing video properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, dom, reactjs

This is the code:

```
render: function () {
    switch (this.state.mime) {
      case "image":
        return React.createElement("img", React.__spread({}, this.props, { className: "img-responsive",
          src: this.state.url }));
      case "iframe":
        return React.createElement("iframe", React.__spread({}, this.props, { src: this.state.url }));
      case "rtmp":
        return React.createElement("embed", React.__spread({}, this.props, { src: this.state.streamUrl,
          type: "video/quicktime",
          autoPlay: true,
          qtsrc: this.state.streamUrl,
          target: "myself",
          scale: "tofit",
          controller: false,
          pluginspage: "http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/",
          loop: "false" }));
      default:
        return React.createElement("span", null);
    }
  }
```

this is the desired output:

```
<embed class="embed-responsive-item" src="rtsp://usr:pwd@10.0.1.12:10012" type="video/quicktime" autoplay="true" qtsrc="rtsp://10.0.1.12:10012" target="myself" scale="tofit" controller="false" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" loop="false" data-reactid=".0.0.1.1.0.0.0.0">
```

and here is what I get:

```
<embed class="embed-responsive-item" src="rtsp://usr:pwd@10.0.1.12:10012" type="video/quicktime" autoplay="" target="myself" loop="" data-reactid=".0.0.1.1.0.0.0.0">
```

- missing elements: *autoPlay value, qtsrc and value, scale, controller, pluginspage and value, loop value*; can't figure out the reason. Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html#custom-html-attributes

Comment: Thanks! I tried but -obviously I am missing something- it just doesn't happen ... it even stops rendering

Comment: I did something like this http://jsbin.com/viveci/2/

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla your solution works! Still not perfect due to the Quicktime plugin acting incoherent that could be related to camera authentication or caching(?). Thanks a lot, I will finish from here!

Comment: I posted the above snippet as an answer so that other users can also benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render: function () {
    switch (this.state.mime) {
      case "image":
        return React.createElement("img", React.__spread({}, this.props, { className: "img-responsive",
          src: this.state.url }));
      case "iframe":
        return React.createElement("iframe", React.__spread({}, this.props, { src: this.state.url }));
      case "rtmp":


        var _unsafeHtml = "<embed " + 
        "src=\"" + this.state.streamUrl + "\" " + 
        "type=\"video/quicktime\" " + 
        "width=\"512\" " + 
        "height=\"288\" " + 
        "autoPlay=\"true\" " + 
        "qtsrc=\"" + this.state.streamUrl + "\" " + 
        "target=\"myself\" " + 
        "scale=\"tofit\" " + 
        "controller=\"false\" " + 
        "pluginspage=\"http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/\" " + 
        "loop=\"false\"/>";

        return React.createElement("div", { dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: _unsafeHtml } });
      default:
        return React.createElement("span", null);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
   var App = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function(){
      return {'streamUrl' : 'http://google.com'};
   },
   render: function(){
      return React.createElement("embed", { src: this.state.streamUrl,
      type: "video/quicktime",
      autoPlay: true,
      "data-qtsrc": this.state.streamUrl,
      target: "myself",
      "scale": "tofit",
      "data-controller": false,
      "data-pluginspage": "http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/",
      loop: "false" }, this.props);
   }
 });
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/viveci/2/edit?html,output)

Comment: Yes, I got to the same point but the video attributes are still missing. After adding `width: 500, height: 350,` the `"scale": "tofit",` should resize the video to fit the 500x350 window but it is completely ignored.

Comment: I am out of thoughts and I would write a custom component in such case :D

Comment: Thank you @Dhiraj Bodicherla same here. Probably I will receive the solution today and will post it here when it works.

Comment: Escaping quotes did part of the job, below is the working script. Thanks again @Dhiraj Bodicherla

Comment: i knew about dangerouslySetInnerHTML just didn't want to use them. But the solution looks fine. And you're welcome